# How can I change language in param of REST API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, localisation, magento2.2.6, translate

I want to change language in REST API.

ex.

1. integration/customer/token for Japanese is "error message = Japanese translation"
2. integration/customer/token for English is "error message = English translation"

Can I ?

I tried
http://[mydomain/rest/[store_id]/V1/integration/customer/token

store_id = Japanese locale store, I set. (Default store is English locale)

=> response error message is English. ( I want Japanese response ...)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the **store code** before the `/V1/`

**Example**

- you have **2 store** views (`store_en/store_ja`) English and Japanese
- if you call this api `/store_en/V1/products`, then you will retrieve
  all products for the `store_en` store view
- if you call this api `/store_ja/V1/products`, then you will retrieve
  all products for the `store_ja` store view

> so you only need to put the **store code** before the /V1/

Comment: Thank you for your information, but This is not I want.

Comment: I know, product API response is change language by store language.
I want " error message language change" (ex. intengration, customer, ...)...

Comment: okay add note in question.